# Efficient way to map a long list of strings to enums

Tags: c++, search, mapping

*(I am not sure how to correctly call my problem. Please edit the title if there as better way to state it)*

In an API I'm using I have a certain enumerator type with 2000+ enumarator values. My objective is to have a function that will take in a string and return the corresponding enumerator. (The enumerator values and the strings2 have almost the same names.)

My idea was to have nested if statements like this:

(`queriedEntityNameString` is a `std::string` and `queriedEntityType` is a enum type)

```
//P
if (queriedEntityNameString[0] == 'p'){

    //PO
    if (queriedEntityNameString[1] == 'o'){

        if (queriedEntityNameString == "point")
            queriedEntityType = et_point;

        else if (queriedEntityNameString == "pocket")
            queriedEntityType = et_pocket;

        else if (queriedEntityNameString == "point_on_curve")
            queriedEntityType = et_point_on_curve;


    }
    //PR
    else if (queriedEntityNameString[1] == 'r'){

        if (queriedEntityNameString == "product")
            queriedEntityType = et_product;

        else if (queriedEntityNameString == "product_definition")
            queriedEntityType = et_product_definition;          

        else if (queriedEntityNameString == "product_definition_formation")
            queriedEntityType = et_product_definition_formation;

    }

}
//Q
else if (queriedEntityNameString[0] == 'q'){
    //QU
    if (queriedEntityNameString[1] == 'u'){

        if (queriedEntityNameString == "qualified_representation_item")
            queriedEntityType = et_qualified_representation_item;

        else if (queriedEntityNameString == "quantified_assembly_component_usage")
            queriedEntityType = et_quantified_assembly_component_usage;

    }
}
```

Obviously setting this up for 2000 cases manually is "impossible". I could write up a little script that could do this for me, but is this sort script available somewhere?

My second idea was to put everything in a std::map, but I'm not sure how efficient it would be.

I would like any suggestions on the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: Since an `enum` is really just an integer value with a fancy name and the actual name doesn't occur anywhere in the actual assembly you're out of luck when it comes to automizing this situation.

Comment: Yes I'm aware it's basically just an integer, and there is no way c++ would automate this. My hope was that there is a script out there that would take in a list of strings and write a text file with nested if statements I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chain of if-then-else conditions builds a "poor man's" [*trie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. It is efficient, but it is probably an overkill in your situation.

A better approach is to use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), a hash-based container, which retrieves values associated with keys in O(k), where `k` is the size of the key (in your case, max length of the string).

Note that the time is not dependent on how many items you have in your map. This is different from [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), which needs O(log<sub>2</sub>n * k) time, where `n` is the number of items in the map.

Comment: Ok, if std::unordered_map is independent of the amount of values, that sounds like a good idea. It would easier to make a little script that takes the 2000 strings and create the c++ code needed for filling the map, than a script that writes the if statements.

Comment: `std::map` may be faster if strings are so long that the overhead of hashing necessary for `std::unordered_map` becomes noticable. It has to be profiled.

Answer (score 0):

How fast do you really need it to be?

The simplest way is to use an array, assuming that your enums are ordered 0 to n-1:

```
enum class ProductProperty : unsigned { ... };

struct ProductProperties
{
    static constexpr char const * NAMES [] = { ... };
    static ProductProperty parse ( char const * const str )
    {
        auto const comparer = [str] ( char const * str_rep ) { return not strcmp ( str, str_rep ); };
        auto const position = std::find_if ( std::begin ( NAMES ), std::end ( NAMES ). comparer );
        return (ProductProperty) ( position - std::begin ( NAMES ) );
    }
}
```

If you want to be fancy, you can build a custom hash function `h` that you verified to be injective on the domain of valid enums, then order the array with regards to `h`. Then the parsing of a string will be equivalent to hashing with `h`, doing a binary search, then 1 more `strcmp` with the target entry, if any.

Comment: I like the idea of just using an array, that's probably the simplest, but maybe slightly slow. I'm not sure if I understand your struct code there..